# Decimate particle instances

Tags: mesh, particles, modular-tree-addon

I am trying to make a pine tree. I used a sapling tree generator to create the trunk, created a needle model, and used particle instances to populate the needles.

As the needles are relatively small, the tree starts to look well only when I use hundreds of thousands of needles:
[image: pine tree]

I would like to populate the landscape with these trees, creating a couple of hundreds of them. This is infeasible with so many particles each. I would like to create a low-poly version of the tree that I generated.

I tried adding the decimate modifier after the particle system, but it only affects the (relatively low-poly) trunk (emitter). I tried instantiating the particle instances to merge them and apply decimate after, but this is already infeasible.

Is there a way to create the decimated mesh without realizing the instances first?

Comment: i think the "pro's" do it like this: they have very low poly trees in the far background (which might even don't have needles), high poly trees only in the absolute foreground (like your tree) and another "mid - poly" tree a bit away from foreground. (and maybe they even have more tree models for different distances).

Comment: Maybe these youtube tutorials can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72LPW4S8bns https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf5dho10OfI

Comment: @Chris: sure, the question is: how do I generate these low-poly trees, other than downloading them from the internet (where I didn't find ones matching what I'd like to have)? :)

Comment: @YousufChaudhry: in both of these tutorials the part between creating a particles system and baking it into a single mesh is skipped. :(

Comment: @sygi it's not skipped, and as to what I remember, just apply the particle instances, Shift select your trunk, and press Ctrl+J to join. Done :)

Comment: @sygi see some youtube tutorials on how to make a low poly pine tree if the tutorials plus my comment doesn't help you.